# Passar valores de um popup (filho) para página pai

Tags: javascript, html, popup

A janela pai (jsp) tem um botão para abrir o popup (filho).

```
<input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Call Child Window" />
```

Quando abre o popup, há campos de texto para a pessoa digitar uma palavra.
Esses `input` são criados dinamicamente, com um botão e uma função para criar mais `input`. Os valores digitados nos `input` são armazenados em um array e o `qtdeCampos` é a quantidade de campos.
A função dos botões:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var qtdeCampos = 0;
function addCampos() {
   var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
   var objFilho = document.createElement("div");//Criando o elemento DIV;
   objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);//Definindo atributos ao objFilho
   objPai.appendChild(objFilho);//Inserindo o elemento no pai
   //Escrevendo algo no filho recém-criado:
   document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='ctxt"+qtdeCampos+"' name='campo[]'>\n\<input type='button' onclick='removerCampo("+qtdeCampos+")' value='Apagar campo'>";
   qtdeCampos++;
}    
</script>
```

Gostaria de saber como passar esse array de palavras digitadas no popup para a página pai.
A página pai o receberá em um array.

Comment: Precisas mesmo de abrir uma nova janela? não seria melhor com um dialog?

Comment: @Sergio acredito que sim, pois podem ser várias inserções de palavras! Há uma função no popup que permiti abrir vários campos de text.

Comment: No popup existe um input texto que o cliente irá digitar algo. Você quer pegar esse valor e enviar para o jsp que o chamou. Para aonde exatamente você quer enviar? Para uma div q existe no jsp pai? Para outro input?

Comment: @Matheus para uma div que existe no JSP pai.

Comment: @Pacíficão Mais uma coisa, enviar no momento que o usuario está escrevendo ou quando o usuario sair do input ou quando o usuario clicar em um botão "enviar"?

Comment: @Matheus ao clicar no botão enviar.

Comment: @Pacíficão, todas as respostas já respondem sua pergunta `Como passar dados do popup para a página pai`, o que você precisa agora é entender as respostas. Em todas as respostas o valor do popup foi salvo em algum lugar da página pai, agora o que você precisa é saber como manipular esse valor na página pai, acho que você precisa de outra pergunta ou apenas olhar mais atento as respostas que já foram dadas a você.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que você tenha esses inputs no popup:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">    
<input type="text" id="senha" name="senha" class="form-control">    
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="enviaDados()">Envia Dados</button>
```

Ao clicar no botão Envia Dados, será chamado a função definida no onclick, sendo ela enviaDados(), onde a função irá pegar os valores do input e colocar na div que você definiu no jsp pai.

```
<script>
  function enviaDados(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var senha = $("#senha").val();

    //insere os valores nas div pai pelo id da div que você definir.
    $("#div1").text(email);
    $("#div2").text(senha);
  }
</script>
```

Para essa solução, foi utilizado **JavaScript** e **Jquery**.

> ***Edit***

Complementando a resposta após a alteração da pergunta.

Na nova função, o jquery irá percorrer todos os inputs com o id **ctxt**, pegando o valor de cada input e inserindo na div com o id "idPai".

```
function enviaDados(){
    $("#idPai").html(""); // Aqui irá resetar o conteudo da div.
    $('input[id^="ctxt"]').each(function(){
        $("#idPai").append("<p><b> Valor do Imput: "+$(this).val()+"</b></p>");
    });  
}
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/p0L2g7wp/1/

Comment: Como eu receberia esses valores na minha página pai?

Comment: @Pacíficão Ele pega os valores das variaveis email e senha, e joga numa div q tu definio na pagina pai

Comment: Ainda não entendi como será o código na página pai. Além do que, atualizei a pergunta, pois tenho um vetor com as respostas.

Comment: @Pacíficão Ainda não está claro, qual elemento na page pai que tu quer enviar ( numa div, numa campo de texto ), isso que ficou vago na tua explicação. Defina exatamente qual o elemento na page pai que você quer enviar, para eu poder editar a responsta.

Comment: Em uma div mesmo. Por favor, atualize a resposta com um exemplo da página pai. E não esqueça que mudei a pergunta, mostrando que é um vetor com várias "respostas" dos inputs

Comment: @Pacíficão Em uma div eh muito vago, pq olha soh, eu vou jogar só o texto dentro dessa div? Não né. Então defina mais, exemplo: Quero os dados dos input dentro de uma div com o id="pai", onde cada valor do input deve ser inserido dentro de uma tag <p>.

Comment: isso é um problema tbm. Como não sei como retornar os valores, não sei como posso receber eles na pagina pai. Pode ser que cada valor do input seja inserido dentro de uma tag <p>, o que preciso no final é que (como minha pág é JSP) eu posso colocar esse array que vem do popup em um array na página pai. Não sei se consegui me expressar bem. Deu pra entender?

Comment: @Pacíficão Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: eu até consegui entender como mandar para a página pai, mas ainda nao sei como receber essa div na página pai. De toda maneira, para tal pergunta, sua resposta foi a mais completa. Farei outra pergunta para entender como manipular na página pai.

Answer (score 5):

Da pra fazer com HTML puro. Basta configurar o atributo `target` como `_parent` no seu formulário:

```
<form target="_parent"></form>
```

Dessa forma o formulário será submetido na janela pai, ou seja, a janela por meio da qual você abriu o pop-up.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a propriedade [window.opener.document](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) para manipular qualquer elemento na página pai.

```
var $botaoFechar = document.getElementById('botaoFechar');
$botaoFechar.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //Elemento na página chamadora que será adicionado o valor da filho
    var $meuTextBoxPai = window.opener.document.getElementById('Ptxt');
    //Elemento do popup com os dados a serem transferidos
    var $meuTextBoxFilho = document.getElementById('ctxt');

    $meuTextBoxPai.value = $meuTextBoxFilho.value;
    $meuTextBoxPai.focus();
    window.close();
});
```

Explicando o exemplo:

- Adicionei um evento click para o elemento com id `meuBotao`
- Busco um elemento com id `meuTextBox` (você pode manipular qualquer elemento) da página chamadora (pai)
- Atribuo a esse elemento o valor que eu desejar
- Em seguida atribuo o foco a ele
- E por fim, fecho o popup

Comment: OK, esse é código que estaria no meu popup. Mas como fica a página pai??

Comment: O que você quer fazer na página pai? Te dei um exemplo de como fazer para enviar um dado qualquer do seu popup para qualquer lugar da tua página chamadora. Agora você decide para onde enviar essa informação e o que fazer com ela. Simples assim.

Comment: O problema que é um array que quero passar para a página pai. Funciona da mesma maneira?? 
E sobre o que fazer na página pai, preciso colocar em um vetor.

Comment: @Pacíficão, editei a pergunta usando os campos com o mesmo nome que você usou na outra pergunta. Procure não repetir a mesma pergunta, você pode editar sua pergunta quantas vezes for necessário para disponibilizar mais informações.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ficar melhor com um melhor entendimento sobre minha dúvida. Veja q na sua resposta, vc pega `document.getElementById('ctxt'); ` e na minha função cada id é ctxt+numero.